# Does Solr have an API to read schema.xml?

Tags: solr, schema, facet

Is there any Solr API to read the Solr schema.xml?

The reason I need it is that Solr faceting is not backwards compatible. If the index doesn't define field A, but the program tries to generate facets for field A, all the facets will fail. Therefore I need to check in the runtime what fields we have in the index, and generate the facets dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the schema with `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema.xml`

It's the raw xml, so have to parse it to get the information you need.

However, if your program generates an invalid facet, maybe you should just fix the program instead of trying to work around this.

Comment: Dose solr have api to read it? I noticed that api for reading solrconf.xml is avaliable. However I cannot find the one for schema.xml

Comment: @Qing Zhang : what's your client platform?

Comment: How to read solrconf.xml via api, any link to doc? I tried to find, but unable to find it.

Answer (score 8):

Since Solr 4.2 the Schema REST API allows you to get the schema with :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/schema
```

or with a core name :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycorename/schema
```

Since Solr 4.4 you may also modify your schema.

[more details on the Solr Wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaRESTAPI)

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use LukeRequestHandler. It is modeled after [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) tool which is used to diagnose the content of Lucene Index. The query /admin/luke?show=schema, will show you the schema. However, you will need to define it in solrconfig.xml like so :

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/luke" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.LukeRequestHandler" />
```

Documentation of LukeRequestHandler [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have the Schema API for that.
The Solr schema API allows using a REST API to get information about the schema.xml

In Solr 4.2 and 4.3, it only allows GET (read-only) access, but in
Solr 4.4, new fields and copyField directives may be added to the schema. Future Solr releases will extend this functionality to allow more schema
elements to be updated

**API Entry Points**

```
/collection/schema: retrieve the entire schema
/collection/schema/fields: retrieve information about all defined fields, or create new     fields with optional copyField directives
/collection/schema/fields/name: retrieve information about a named field, or create a new named field with optional copyField directives
/collection/schema/dynamicfields: retrieve information about dynamic field rules
/collection/schema/dynamicfields/name: retrieve information about a named dynamic rule
/collection/schema/fieldtypes: retrieve information about field types
/collection/schema/fieldtypes/name: retrieve information about a named field type
/collection/schema/copyfields: retrieve information about copy fields, or create new copyField directives
/collection/schema/name: retrieve the schema name
/collection/schema/version: retrieve the schema version
/collection/schema/uniquekey: retrieve the defined uniqueKey
/collection/schema/similarity: retrieve the global similarity definition
/collection/schema/solrqueryparser/defaultoperator: retrieve the default operator
```

**Examples**

Input
Get a list of all fields.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/schema/fields?wt=json
```

Input
Get the entire schema in JSON.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/schema?wt=json
```

More info [here: apache-solr-ref-guide-4.5.pdf](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.5.pdf)  (search for Schema API)