# solr 5.3.1 verifying that schema.xml is loaded

Tags: xml, solr, django-haystack

I'm configuring solr with django-haystack and one of the steps of configuration is to generate `schema.xml` with the following command and then place the resulting file in solr config direcotory:

```
$ python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

Currently I'm having some issues indexing file content, and several possible fixes are pointing edits at `schema.xml` However, solar has `schema.xml` in several places:

```
$ find . -name schema.xml

./solr/solrj/src/test-files/solrj/solr/configsets/configset-2/conf/schema.xml
./solr/solrj/src/test-files/solrj/solr/configsets/shared/conf/schema.xml
./solr/solrj/src/test-files/solrj/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/solrj/src/test-files/solrj/solr/multicore/core0/conf/schema.xml
./solr/solrj/src/test-files/solrj/solr/multicore/core1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/schema.xml
./solr/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/schema.xml
./solr/example/example-DIH/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml
./solr/example/example-DIH/solr/rss/conf/schema.xml
./solr/example/example-DIH/solr/mail/conf/schema.xml
./solr/example/example-DIH/solr/tika/conf/schema.xml
./solr/example/example-DIH/solr/db/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/morphlines-core/src/test-files/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/morphlines-core/src/test-files/solr/minimr/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/morphlines-core/src/test-files/solr/mrunit/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/morphlines-core/src/test-files/solr/solrcelltest/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/extraction/src/test-files/extraction/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/uima/src/test-files/uima/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/clustering/src/test-files/clustering/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/velocity/src/test-files/velocity/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/contrib/langid/src/test-files/langid/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
./solr/core/src/test-files/solr/configsets/bad-mergepolicy/conf/schema.xml
./solr/core/src/test-files/solr/configsets/minimal/conf/schema.xml
./solr/core/src/test-files/solr/configsets/configset-2/conf/schema.xml
./solr/core/src/test-files/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
```

I tried changing several of those files, but I'm getting no feedback whatsover.I deleted all of the files and solr works in the default configuration as if nothing happened.

I tried going to the following url to extract and verify the schema -- http://localhost:8983/solr/schema but that also didn't work.

I'm looking on the log files in `solr/node1/logs` and `solr/node2/logs` but they don't seem to bring up any errors or any information related to `schema.xml`

The documentation is very confusing as solr behaviour has changed in the major way between releases, which renders documentation rather contradictory.

Is there a proven, repeatable way for Solr 5.3.1 of checking loaded schema.xml configuration or a possibility of dumping said schema in a file to be examined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I describe various Solr 5.3.1 examples and their homes in [this blog article](http://blog.outerthoughts.com/2015/11/oh-solr-home-where-art-thou/).

The location of the core's directory is listed in the Solr Admin UI's [overview page for the core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Core-Specific+Tools).

Comment: Oh, thank you, all of this finally makes sense and I wish I could have found this post earlier so I wouldn’t have to spend all that time researching this myself.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to what I'm asking -- [Does solr has API to read solr schema.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247221/does-solr-has-api-to-read-solr-schema-xml)

This answer led me to a solution -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874263/86294

Which is this document, describing schema api -- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API

The url that needs to be constructed in Solr 5.3.1 is -- http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema

It returns schema.xml in browser as plain text and it is possible to work with.

**Update:**

I also found the following instructions enormously useful -- https://github.com/nazariyg/Solr-5-for-django-haystack

Related issues in django_haystack project: [#1182](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1182), [#1183](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1183)